# Cannot run setup.exe in Dockerfile with PowerShell start-process

Tags: powershell, docker, devops, docker-for-windows

I have a simple docker windows-based image, one of the thing it does is to run a setup.exe to install some stuff.

This setup.exe when being run in the windows UI, installs stuff into `C:/Program Files x86/Common Files/someFolder`. When being run inside a powershell, it works. But when being run with docker, it does not. Details below.

**Building the docker image, where you can see the setup starts, but there's not a long going on...**

```
λ docker build -t test -f Dockerfile-test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  286.8MB
Step 1/4 : FROM stefanscherer/node-windows
 ---> 736520eb3998
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 039fd8f0cd4a
Step 3/4 : COPY ./binaries ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9fdaa51ee64d
Step 4/4 : RUN powershell.exe -Command Start-Process -FilePath setup.exe -PassThru -Wait
 ---> Running in 5676e0e08c6d

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
              0        0          0              4260


Removing intermediate container 5676e0e08c6d
 ---> 98d9f0818c5c
Successfully built 98d9f0818c5c
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

**Running the setup.exe inside a powershell :**

```
PS C:\Users\...\binaries> Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/S" -PassThru

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
      0       2      492         88       0,03   1244   1 setup
```

**Then, `cmd` into the container**

```
λ docker run -it test cmd

> C:/app/>  cd ..
> C:/> cd "Program Files (x86)"
> C:/Program Files (x86)> cd "Common Files"
> C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files> dir
*empty*
```

The `setup.exe` is supposed to install files inside `common files`, but it's empty.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you need to pass something to make setup.exe work in unattanded mode may be? Did you try to run the same setup.exe in server core OS without docker?

Comment: How does `cmd` come into play? Your two commands don't match; only the 2nd one passes argument `/S` (and doesn't use `-Wait`). Please clarify by updating your question directly.

Comment: @mklement0 I added the extra step. Basicly it's running the container to check if the setup went fine.

Comment: @GregorySuvalian when running the setup.exe in the UI, you just have to click "install" and it does everything for you. You have to click once, then it's done. Is there an argument that I need to pass to `start-process` to do that ?

Comment: There is no UI in docker container so whatever command you run you need to make sure it can be run with no user interaction. Either check all your steps inside server core container or directly by running in container itself

Comment: @MarcelFalliere: It's not an argument for `Start-Process` you need to add, but for `setup.exe`, _if_ the latter supports silent (no-GUI, no user interaction) installation. Maybe that is what the `/S` does in your standalone command? As stated, that argument is missing from your Docker-file command.

Comment: I found two possible solutions : 1/ I switched the `FROM` directive `stefanscherer/node-windows` to `microsoft/windowsservercore` and 2/ added the `-NoNewWindow` switch to `start-process`. Don't know which one fixed the issue.